# Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBBox' of null

Tags: javascript, d3.js

Im trying to replicate [this codepen](https://codepen.io/niamleeson/pen/dpJWkZ) However I get the error:

```
 tank.js:441 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'getBBox' of null
    at AnalogTank.calculateArrowPosition (tank.js:441)
    at AnalogTank.applyArrowAttribute (tank.js:408)
    at AnalogTank.addArrow (tank.js:404)
    at AnalogTank.initTower (tank.js:316)
    at AnalogTank.init (tank.js:126)
    at new AnalogTank (tank.js:113)
    at jQuery.fn.init.$.fn.analogTank (tank.js:105)
    at tank.js:1124
```

It seems the version of d3 in src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.js"> may be part of the problem but I do not know how to correct the error.

Here is my HTML head for reference.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>


<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=no" />
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/4.2.3/d3.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
        <script type="text/javascript" src="tank.js"></script>

        <link rel="stylesheet" href="tank.css" />


    </head>
```

Comment: What does `tank.js` line 1124 say?

Comment: @BenRondeau }(jQuery));
let tank = $('.wrapper').analogTank({ just as in the codepen.

Answer (score 0):

I should not have tried loading my tank.js until after the HTML had loaded. I simply moved the  tag for tank.js down to the bottom of the document.